# FirebaseStorage + Flutter , streamBuilder?

Tags: image, listview, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

is it possible to get images from the Firebasestorage with a streamBuilder ? 
Or any other way to get a listView of images loaded from the google Firesbase Storage?

Thank by advance for your answers.

Comment: I think that you will need to reference each file individually. You could store the file path's in a database though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I've done it with a streamBuilder and the cloud firestore. 
Each time I push a new image in the Storage, I also create a document in the cloud firestore with the path of the image from the storage and I could get it with the StreamBuilder :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was talking about, nice! Great to hear that. It would be very nice if you posted this as an answer to your question. This way, you will be able to **accept** your own answer and mark the question as answered.

Comment: Ok I will do it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've done it with a streamBuilder and the cloud firestore. Each time I push a new image in the Storage, I also create a document in the cloud firestore with the path of the image from the storage and I could get it with the StreamBuilder :)

Comment: Hi, is the permissions on your firebaseStorage are public or Auth only?

Comment: Im struggling with something similar, I want to have the getDownloadURL string in a stream so that it can be accessed by multiple places in a widget tree and be constantly up to date whenever its changed. Is this sort of what you figured out?